# Can't get data from server with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have the following code:

```
private static final String Tag = "DataUtil";

    static List<Film> generateFilms(){
        Log.i(Tag, "In generate films");
        List  <Film> films = new ArrayList<>();
        String BaseUrl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=956febbc&";
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        APIService apiService  = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        final Call<List<Film>> filmsCall = apiService.getFilms();
        filmsCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Film>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Film>> call, Response<List<Film>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.i(Tag, response.body().get(0).getTitle());
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(Tag, "Response code: "+response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Film>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: "+t);
            }
        });

        return films;
    }
```

This code should get data form [this](http://www.omdbapi.com/) site. Here's the interface, which is used for getting data (in this way I get infromation about Batman film):

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET("t=batman")
    Call<List<Film>> getFilms();

}
```

Line `Log.i(Tag, response.body().get(0).getTitle())` doesn't add any lines to logger => there's no data in response. At the same time, lines `Log.i(Tag, "Response code: "+response.code()); и Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: "+t)` don't add anything either. So, what's the matter?

**UPD**

When I added Interceptor I found the following line in logcat:

```
I/: Error: java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to www.omdbapi.com not permitted by network security policy
```

Comment: Based on what i know the base url in Retrofit should end on a slash. Try to have your base url like "omdbapi.com/", and move the api key to your interface as @GET("?apikey=956febbc&t=batman"). Hope this helps.

Comment: @DanielSpiess unfortunately when I changed in such way that         `String BaseUrl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/";` and in interface `    @GET("?apikey=956febbc&t=batman")` nothing is changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String BaseUrl = "http://www.omdbapi.com";
```

get use query

```
@GET(".")
Call<Film> getFilms(@Query("apikey") String apikey, @Query("t") String t);
```

request data `apiService.getFilms("956febbc", "batman")`